# Multiplicar todos los elementos numéricos dentro de un array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Tenemos por ejemplo el array: [1,2,5,7,12,3,9]
¿Como podria multiplicar todos los elementos de el array sin utilizar un bucle for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer uso de numpy, el mismo tiene un método conocido como **prod** el cual multiplica todos los elementos dentro de un array.

```
<< import numpy as np
<< a = [1,2,3,4]
<< print(np.prod(a))
>> 24
```

Espero te haya servido mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Sin numpy sería :

```
import operator
import functools
functools.reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,5,7,12,3,9])
```

Puedes ver la documentación de reduce : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Básicamente ejecuta una funcion de dos argumentos de forma acumulativa en una lista de elementos, en este caso mul, pero puedes usar otros "operadores como funciones", como "sub" o "add", la lista completa aquí https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo, sin usar numpy:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> items = [1,2,5,7,12,3,9]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, items)
22680
```

Answer (score 1):

No es muy pythonica, pero esta opción no usa for-loop:

```
arr = [1,2,5,7,12,3,9]
i = 0
prod = 1
while i < len(arr):
    prod = prod * arr[i]
    i += 1
print(prod)
```